# how to change background and colors of vim with vimrc plugin?

Tags: console, terminal, vim, vi

I have a problem using Vim colorschemes. I've downloaded and installed [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=625) but I don't know how to make my choice permanent.

Could you tell me how to do it?

Here is a part of my `.vimrc` config file:

```
set nocompatible        " not compatible with the old-fashion vi mode
set bs=2                " allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set history=50          " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler               " show the cursor position all the time
set autoread            " auto read when file is changed from outside
set number              " setting number always 
set showcmd             " display an incomplete command 
set background=wombat256     " or light
```

I've chosen `wombat256` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
set background=wombat256     " or light
```

to

```
colorscheme wombat256
```

And don't pass a great opportunity to read the documentation: `:help 'background'` and `:help colorscheme`.

Comment: that is work but, i must adding this code set `term=xterm-256color` before, and `colorscheme wombat256`.